# convert index from rangeindex to datetime index error

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date         P1     P2     P3     P4 ...
2014-01-03   2      4      9      8
...
```

It is a daily time series data. I want to aggregate it to a monthly level. I need to note, that before, it had some missing days, so I added those missing days with `reindex`.

When I try to aggregate the data with `resample`, I get the following `error`:
`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Even when I convert the index to `DatetimeIndex`.

This is my code:

```
ts_data = ts_data.set_index("Date")
ts_data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ts_data.index)
ts_data_w = ts_data.reindex(pd.date_range("2014-01-03", "2017-12-30"))
ts_data_w.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ts_data_w.index)
ts_data_w.index.name = "Order_Date"

# Filling missing values with KNN
imputer_knn = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform', metric='nan_euclidean')
ts_data_d = pd.DataFrame(imputer_knn.fit_transform(ts_data_w), columns=ts_data_w.columns)
# ts_data_d#.isnull().values.any()

# Month level aggregation
dicti = {c: "sum" for i, c in enumerate(ts_data_d.columns)}
ts_data_m = ts_data_d.resample('M').agg(dicti)
ts_data_m
```

The `dicti` is just to get the columns with `sum` for aggregation.
This is the error line `ts_data_m = ts_data_d.resample('M').agg(dicti)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even when I convert the index to `DatetimeIndex`.

You only convert the index of `ts_data_w` to `DatetimeIndex`, you may do

```py
ts_data_d = pd.DataFrame(imputer_knn.fit_transform(ts_data_w),
                         columns=ts_data_w.columns,
                         index=ts_data_w.index)  # Added here
```